# set the ngModel value as the input's value

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I am trying to call the function inside **[(ngModel)]** but it give me error **Unexpected token '=' at column 27 in [sum(data,'feeAssign') || 0=$event]**

**json data**

```
 { "org_Id": 1, "academic_Id": 1, "fee_Category_Id": 5, "type_Id": 12, "duration_Id": 2, "structure_Id": 59, "sub_structure_Id": 18, "installment_Id": 1, "type_Det_Name": "Term Fees - Term", "student_Id": 0, "receipt_Id": 0, "receipt_Code": 0, "structure_Amount": 4, "discountAmount": 0, "receipt_Amount": 0, "responseCode": 0, "responseMessage": "Fee Collection Received Succesfully", "feeAssign": 4, "paid": 0, "feeBalance": 4, "payable": 4 }
```

**html component code**

```
 <nz-input-number [nzDisabled]="true" [(ngModel)]="sum(data,'feeAssign') || 0"  [nzMin]="1" 
[nzStep]="1">
 </nz-input-number>
```

**.ts file code**

```
 sum(array, key) { 
return array.reduce(function (sum, current) {
  debugger;
    return sum + current[key];
}, 0);
}
```

I tried with **[ngModel]** there is **no error** but it is not calling the sum function in that case.

I want to call the function which sum the value in array and returned the updated values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only [ngModel]:  [ngModel]="sum(data,'feeAssign') || 0"

one-way binding to ngModel with [] syntax

Comment: If I use [ngModel]="sum(data,'feeAssign') || 0" than sum function is not called.

Comment: I want to update the textbox value by sum up the values in array by respective key

Comment: this is an example with simple input type number : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbmbd7

Comment: thanx for the example but I tried the same and its strange why sum function is not calling in my case.

Comment: it is giving me error array.reduce is not a function. If I write like this {{sum(data, 'feeAssign')}}

Comment: its work for me but you can add array?.reduce